# How to feed Vue.js variable into php function?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I have a Laravel 5.1 project that I'm trying to improve and now migrating some features to `Vue.js` to make it more interactive and stuff.

In my view I have

```
<img src="{{ file_storage_path($product->path) }}" alt="{{$product->name}}"/>
```

This is default implementation using Laravel's `blade`.

Now, when I delegate this to the `Vue.js` I would have something like this

```
<img src="{{ file_storage_path(product.path) }}" alt="@{{product.name}}"/>
```

But this of course fails. So I need both - to invoke a `php-function` and at the same time to render `Vue` data.

I tried this

```
src="{{ file_storage_path( @{{product.path}} ) }}"
```

But of course this fails too. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find a way to inline both blade syntax and `Vue.js` variable rendering I see the solution is to first invoke the php function and then append the `Vue.js` rendering to it.

So, the workaround would be

```
 <img :src="'{{ file_storage_path('/') }}' + image.path" alt="@{{product.name}}" />
```

This solution would work only for specific case, it doesn't get answer to my original question, when a php function actually needs to accept a Vue variable. But in this case, I can simply append values.

Comment: @RohitGupta there is nothing actually edit or explain. I found a working solution and posted it as someone might be facing same problem

Comment: As it stands the answer is pending deletion as being low quality.  The way you improve it is to explain it.  Are you saying, you do not understand your own answer ?

Comment: @AndrewMalinnkov Really, code-only answer isn't a good answer. Explain what are you doing, why are you doing this is a good idea.